# Node Js - mysql query in session not working

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-mysql, swagger-node-express

Here is my nodejs code.
I getting last inserted id but not getting session value and last inserted id value outside of query function.

```
  app.post('/api/payment', function (req, res) {
        var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO label SET ?', label, function(err, result) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                            console.log(result.insertId); // getting last Inserted Id
                            req.session.label_id=result.insertId;
                     });
            console.log( req.session.label_id); //not getting value

          req.session.label_id=100;
          console.log( req.session.label_id); // result 100
        });
```

Comment: So read up on returning values from asynchronous functions ...